# Adding a new property to a model: converting existing JSON

Tags: json, swift

say I had this model:

```
struct MyModel: Codable {
  var name: String
}
```

By already using this property, I persisted JSON files like this:

```
{"name":"Foo"}
```

Now, I want to add a new property `uuid`, but want to make sure to have a valid migration path to locally persisted existing data. So, I rewrote my struct to this:

```swift
struct MyModel {
  let uuid: UUID
  var name: String
}

extension MyModel: Codable {
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do {
            self.uuid = try container.decode(UUID.self, forKey: .uuid)
        } catch {
            self.uuid = UUID()
        }

        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case uuid
        case name
    }
}
```

My thought process here is to catch the error when not finding the property in the JSON by instantiating it manually when needed.

This leads to the error `The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.`.

I might have to add that to be able to load the locally persisted data, I have built the function `ATPersistLocally.loadAll(of:)` in a personal toolbox package (that I can add to my projects with SPM), that looks like this:

```swift
   public func loadAll<T: Codable & Identifiable>(of type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        var result = [T]()

        let pathFolder = docPath.appendingPathComponent(String(describing: type))
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: pathFolder.path) {
            var urls = [URL]()
            do {
                urls = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: pathFolder, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
            } catch {
                ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Could not load content of directory: \(error.localizedDescription)", type: .error)
            }

            for url in urls {
                if let data = fileManager.contents(atPath: url.path) {
                    do {
                        let instance = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
                        result.append(instance)
                    } catch {
                        ATLogger.shared.logToConsole(message: "Could not decode data: \(error.localizedDescription)", type: .error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }

Any hints on how to resolve this?
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting when trying to decode `UUID` ?

Comment: `The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.` -  which I am aware of and which I am trying to catch...

Comment: have you tried adding optional `?` to `UUID` ?

Comment: I could do that, but I don't want it to be optional from now on, as my model will need this unique identifier in the future. Just trying to do a migration here – but perhaps I will need to seek out for another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `decodeIfPresent`instead in `init(from decoder: Decoder)` together with a local variable

```
if let uuid = try container.decodeIfPresent(UUID.self, forKey: .uuid)  {
    self.uuid = uuid
} else {
    self.uuid = UUID()
}
```

Comment: While this seems super logical to me, it unfortunately leads to the exact same error:
`The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.`. And that is even though I can see in debugging that it takes the right path in the changed init func...

Comment: @ASSeeger Strange, it works fine for me in a playground

Comment: @ASSeeger As mentioned do not print error.localizedDescription, the error might be caused by something else. Use `print(error)`

Comment: Tried in a playground as well and it did work there – so thanks for your answer! Turns out that I had a problem with another optional property in my "real" struct (which I realised by  changing my error-printing thanks to @vadian's hint above.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution: Omit the CodingKey `uuid` to decode only `name` (and you can omit the `init` method, too).

```
struct MyModel {
    let uuid = UUID()
    var name: String
}

extension MyModel: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case name }
}
```

Important note:

**Never print `error.localizedDescription` in a `Decoding` `catch` block, print always only the `error` instance to get the actual descriptive error message.**

Comment: Great answer, but why not adding `UUID` to the `CodingKey` ?

Comment: From my understanding you want to add the property but the JSON doesn't change.

Comment: oh I'm not the OP, but can you edit in case the JSON had the `UUID` to get that value if not to get the instance default ? is it by just adding the case?

Comment: Well, I do want to reflect the changes in my JSON (which I have full power over as it's not from an API). So I guess this is not it or am I overseeing something?

Comment: @MohmmadS If the JSON contains the key you do have to specify the `CodingKey`. Then Joakim's answer is the better choice.

Comment: @vadian thanks for the hint concerning the printing of the error – that definitely did help uncover my mistake!! Will have to choose Joakim's answer for this specific issue.